# Index.html doesn't load css nor script on nested url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The start point of my React app is:

> localhost:3000/Admin

So when i am typing in the url this:

> localhost:3000/admin/dashboard/

It works all right. But when I write the next nested url:

> localhost:3000/admin/dashboard/new

the index.html doesn’t load my script and css. When I change in the index.html the src url from `./js/admin-app.js` to `../../js/admin-app.js` it works but not more on the other urls.

> Localhost:3000/admin/dashboard

I have tried to set in the index.html base `href="./"` but it doesn't work.

I can’t find the problem .

my server.js:

```
app.use('/admin', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin/server/static/')));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'server/static/')));

app.get('/admin/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'admin/server/static/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
});

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'server/static/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="./" />
    <title>AdminPage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin_style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="admin-app"></div>
   <script src="js/admin_app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Solution**
My App runs at

> Localhost:3000/admin/

Instead of

```
 src="js/admin_app.js" or src="./js/admin_app.js"
```

i try this

```
 src="/admin/js/admin_app.js"
```

and it works perfectly

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you please post your index.html and your app.js or whatever your base js file is?

Comment: hi, thanks :) i post at below

Comment: Please `edit` your question and add the code there. Don't add it as an answer. Please move that code to your question, and delete your answer.

Comment: Hi oh sorry. I edit my post

Comment: please mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that we can try.

When setting the index.html, leave the file relative to the base url.

So, instead of:

```
<script src="js/admin_app.js"></script>
```

use:

```
<script src="/js/admin_app.js"></script>
```

This means that the browser will always search for the file in a url relative to the base app, for example:

```
http://localhost/js/admin_app.js
```

or something like:

```
http://myurl.com/js/admin_app.js
```

So your `admin_app.js` file HAS to be in that folder (js). In your case, you have a static folder structure like this:

```
server/static
```

so the file has to be in:

```
server/static/js/admin_app.js
```

This is because in your server you are routing all the requests to `/` into the folder `server/static/`.

Basically, you must point to the correct file using your folder structure. You also have a folder called `admin`, so if the files are in `admin/server/static` then the relative url should be:

```
<script src="/admin/js/admin_app.js"></script>
```

So, it all depends on where the files exactly are in your folder structure.

Do the same for the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin_style.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin/css/admin_style.css">
```

Remove this from your `index.html file` (you don't need it):

```
<base href="./" />
```

Comment: Hey thank a lot. I‘ve tried with /js/admin_app.js but it don’t helps. I add before /admin. /admin/js/admin_app.js and now it works perfectly. :)

Comment: @DennisM. nice, please consider marking this as the correct answer if it helped you, and upvoting it. Thank you!